# Differentiation wrt to L

Tags: derivatives

I need to differentiate a equation which I have some problem with.

The equation looks like this:

$(K-L)(x/L)^{\gamma}$.

I need to differentiate this wrt to L. Not able to do it.

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: what is the other side?

Comment: nothing. differentiate this only..

Comment: [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2FdL%28%28K%E2%88%92L%29%28x%2FL%29%5E%CE%B3%29 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-(x/L)^\gamma+(K-L)(-\gamma)x^\gamma L^{-\gamma-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(L) = (K-L)( \frac{x}{L} )^{\gamma} = K(\frac{x}{L})^\gamma - \frac{x^\gamma}{L^{\gamma - 1}}$

$$\therefore \frac{dF}{dL} = - \gamma K x^{\gamma} L^{-\gamma - 1} - (1 - \gamma)x^\gamma L^{-\gamma}$$

Answer (score 1):

Derivative of $F(L)=(K-L)(x/L)^{\gamma}$ is 
\begin{equation}
F'(L)=\gamma(-K+L)\frac{x^{\gamma}}{L^{\gamma+1}}-(x/L)^{\gamma}
\end{equation}
using the chain and product rule. I can't see any equation in the question though...

Comment: it must be $\gamma+1$

Comment: oops, sorry.. corrected!